# Python using data structure

Tags: python

How to write a logic for the following: Every 3rd element of the input queue  from a front-> rear should be added to output queue otherwise it should return -1.

Example:

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]  # should return 4,7,10 

l=[1,2]                   # should return -1
```

Comment: Any attempt from your side?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes sir what I did is I have divided the index  by 3 if it's equal to zero that element will return but I didn't understand how to return -1@ Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner list comprehension should do the trick:

```
[x for i, x in enumerate(l) if i > 0 and i % 3 == 0] or -1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use slicing for that:

```
l[3::3]
```

this will construct a sublist with the elements at index `3`, `6`, `9`, etc. The problem is of course that this list can be empty. In that case we have to return `-1`. The nice thing is that the *truthiness* of an empty list (and usually an empty collection in general), is `False`. So we can use `or` to provide a value for that case. So a solution is:

```
l[3::3] or -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is without loop approach :

```
track=[]
def every_third(l):
    track.append(l[0])

    if len(l)<3:
        return 0
    else:

        return every_third(l[3:])

print(every_third(l))

if track[1:]:
    print(track[1:])
else:
    print(-1)
```

output:

```
[4, 7, 10]
```

when list is [1,2] then

```
-1
```